# RJ11 pinout (serial) for Amplus AM03128-H11 LED display

Tags: serial, wiring, led-matrix

I've got an Amplus AM03128-H11 LED display, without the documentation and serial cable.
I found the programming manual online, but I have no idea what the pinout on the serial RJ11 connector is supposed to be.
Anyone out there who knows ?
Or who has one of these devices and is willing to check the wiring for me?

Comment: <Looking in crystal ball> Nope, nothing. Either find a datasheet or reverse engineer it by tracing out the connections. If you're lucky the pinout is marked on the PCB.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Give me some credit :-) I already checked the PCB. Tick layer of black glue/paste covers everything. My Google-fu is failing me on the datasheet. Have no trouble finding sample-code to control that display, but everyone seems to assume that you will have the supplied serial cable that came with the thing. And manufacturer doesn't respond to emails.

Comment: Email to Amplus...?

Comment: Guessing this is some obscure de facto standard: http://www.asayo.com/images/products/led-sign-cable/cable-spec.jpg 2,3,4 are RX, TX, GND

Comment: Quick test with a meter may help to see if that's correct.

Comment: @Finbarr Tried to email them. 4 weeks ago. No answer yet.

Comment: @τεκ I found that image myself already and it is possible these Asayo LED signs are a rebrand of the original Amplus ones. The pictures on the site look very similar and one of them shows a multi-color sign that Asayo dind't actually sell but the picture looks very much like the Amplus AM03128-H13 model (which also uses that same cable). Barring any other info I'm going to just try it.